# Deploying a WPF Application With Microsoft.ReportViewer

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, reportviewer

I have a WPF application that connects to a SQL Server database.  The database is installed on a central computer in the office I work in.  This application uses Microsoft.ReportViewer.  I have 3 computers that I need this application to work on.  One is the computer the database is installed on, the application works fine here. Second computer is my computer which the application connects to the database on computer 1 and works fine.  The third computer the application does not work on.  This computer does not have SQL Server installed on it and they do not want it installed.  I was just moving the app.exe file to each computer.  I then tried the Publish option within Microsoft Visual Studio.  When I try to execute the setup created by the Publish option I get an error saying that the "CLR Types for SQL Server have changed".  I literally performed the Publish and then walked over to the other computer.  The issue appears to be the ReportViewer as it needs database information.

I am very familiar with publishing or deploying applications.  How can I deploy a WPF application that uses ReportViewer to a computer that does not have a SQL Server instance installed and connects remotely to the database?  I have looked through the web and nothing, that I can find, tells me how to deploy an app with ReportViewer.  I am stuck and confused.

Comment: Did you add the Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WinForms NuGet Package, per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-reportviewer-controls-get-started?view=sql-server-2017 ?

Comment: David, I did not.  Didn't know I needed to add it.

Comment: I believe that is a newer deployment mechanism.  You used to have to download and install on the client machine using an .MSI.

Comment: David, do I just add this NuGet package to my application then just copy the .exe, or should I still do the publish process from Visual Studio

Comment: Either XCopy or ClickOnce deployment should work at that point.  You can't just copy the .exe, as the ReportViewer .dlls need to be in the same folder.

Comment: David, I used the Publish function in Visual Studio.  When I run the Setup.exe I get this error, "Setup has detected that the file 'C:\Users\bjs\AppData\Local\Temp\VSDFBA2.tmp\SqlClrTypes_x86\SQLSysClrTypes.msi" has changed since it was initially published".  I include the SQLClrTypes in the deployment.  How do I fix this?

Comment: David, do you have any suggestions for my previous comment?  I can't figure this out.

Comment: I suspect you're mixing deployment models.  The _old_ model used MSI installers for ReportViewer and dependencies.  With the NuGet package I don't think you need have any machine-wide .msi installs.

Answer (score -1):

You must have sql server installed on each computer

Or just use web service that connects to the database separately

Or use ms-access you can find it on every computer and your code will not be changed a lote just few ticks and you are done

Comment: ReportViewer is freely redistributable.  It's not full SQL Server Reporting Services; just the viewer.

Comment: I know dude but you are pulling your data from an sql server you can't do it without of downloading sql on the machine

Comment: I don't understand.  You don't need to install SQL Server on every machine that needs data.  SQL Server is a client/server RDBMS. The servers have SQL Server installed, the clients don't.